# MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci 3.0.75.0 breaking change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

Just updated from MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci 3.0.73.0 to 3.0.75, and the previously working plain ViewUserControl threw a runtime exception:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcContrib.UI.InputBuilder.Views.PropertyViewModel`1[System.Object]'.
```

The "offending" editor takes a plain string from the model:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model.NEV) %>
```

Reverting to 3.0.73.0, and the editor works again. Any ideas? (3.0.74.0 also seems to be working)

Comment: Vote to close too localized, this belongs on MvcContrib forums / issue list.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue to and solved it be reverting to version: 3.0.73.0

```
Uninstall-Package MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci -Force
Install-Package MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci -version 3.0.73.0
```

Comment: I had this issue with version 3.0.100.0

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. It seems that if you use anything other than EditorFor it works fine.
So if you know which HTML editor needs to be rendered use that (e.g. @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Model.NEV)